# pulling through data not working on iPHONE

Tags: php, iphone, mysql

have created a mobile site for my client www.-leeds-united-fans.co.uk and the problem is when you view the the latest news is not pulling through for the latest news properly on the home page.

It does not show the latest news item, however when you go to the news section it pulls through all together.

I am using the same coding for both just with a limiter on the latest:

```
    $query = "SELECT * from newsfeed_items order by id desc limit 0,6";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);



while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
echo "<div id=\"featureone\">";
echo "<div class=\"comtitle\"><a href=\"news.php?id=".$row['id']."\" >".$row['title']."</a></div>";
echo "</div>";


}
```

can anyone help please?

Comment: We're gonna need to see more of the code. The SQL statement looks fine from a syntax point of view.

Comment: A little bit of code will be more helpful.

Comment: show us more code. also you might want to put a ; at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never assume a MySQL query goes through without an error. always do some kind of error handling like this:

```
if (!($result=@mysql_query($query, $connection)))
    die('Error ' . mysql_errno() . ": " . mysql_error());
```

This will also give you (and us) some information on what the nature of your error is, and you can google the error number or ask us here.

Comment: thanks for this, have tried the error and nothing is coming through

Comment: if it responds "error: 0", it means that the `if` statement returned true, which means `$result != mysql_query($query, $connection)`, so the quey can not be completed, only MySQL is not returning an error, so the problem is somewhere else.